# How to evaluate this integral $\int\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}-\arccos{\sqrt{x}}}{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}+\arccos{\sqrt{x}}}\cdot dx$?

Tags: integration, analysis, indefinite-integrals, inverse-function

The integral is $$\int\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}-\arccos{\sqrt{x}}}{\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}+\arccos{\sqrt{x}}}\cdot dx$$

What I did was to sum up the denominator to equal $\frac\pi2$ and then applied integration by parts on the remaining $\arccos{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}$ integrals but this process was very lengthy.

Can someone suggest a shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}+\arccos{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and
$$\int\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}=x\arcsin{\sqrt{x}}-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x}}\cdot\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: That's what I did as I've already mentioned. Is this the only feasible way?

Comment: @infinite-blank- I think, this is the way. Use the substitution $\sqrt{\frac{x}{1-x}}=t$.

Comment: No I meant as in- is applying integration by parts the only possible way?

Comment: Yes, I think it's an unique way here. By the way, $\int\arccos\sqrt{x}dx=\frac{\pi}{2}x-\int\arcsin\sqrt{x}dx.$

Comment: Alternatively $$\arcsin\sqrt x=y\implies x=\sin^2y$$